# Lambda is not evaluated till function returns

Tags: java

```
public Resposne some_function(){
Response resp =  null;
try{
           resp =  Response.ok().type(APPLICATION_ZIP).entity((StreamingOutput) out -> {
              //Some code here.
           }).header(CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER, "ABC").build();
}catch()
{
}
return resp.
}
```

Hi,

I have a function similar to the above. The lambda passed to the entity function is not evaluated till the function some_function returns. Looks like Java 8 feature. Any pointers to what could be happening? Also, is there a way to force the evaluation? Thanks.

Comment: When do you think the lambda should be evaluated?

Comment: The lambda is just an object that's passed to the `entity` method. When it is evaluated, depends on what the `entity` method does with it. There's no way (in general) to force it to be executed on the spot. If you want it to be executed immediately, then put the code before the call, instead of passing it as a lambda.

Comment: This isn't specifically executed when the function returns, it's that the calling function is executing it.

Comment: I am expecting the lambda to be evaluated immediately after assignment to "resp" is done. In the same statement

Comment: Looks like you have a misunderstanding what Lambdas are and do. Lambdas are stored functions but not a direct function call. So what ever entity() does with the given function will be the reason why and when the given function is executed. Please provide code auf entity() function.

Comment: I cant share the code that forms lambda. I understand lambda itself are not execution statements but when passed to an another function such as entity I expected it to be evaluated given that entity is chained with other functions and the return value is assigned to a variable..

Comment: Please provide the code of entity(), not the lambda itself. This entitiy() might run (evaluate) the lambda - or maybe not.

Comment: entity is in javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder. Lambda gets evaluated when the function returns. How is it possible that it is somehow tied to variable going out of scope?

Comment: It's evaluated when the framework receives the corresponding `Response`  object and uses it to create a response body. This has nothing to do with scope. You've prepared a response, now the framework serializes it.

Comment: These are all synchronous function. I don't understand what does it mean to say when the framework received the corresponding Response object. I am creating a response object using synchronous function so I expect the lambda to be invoked when entity is invoked. If not what is the trigger/method invocation that is causing the lambda evaluation when function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you're using JAX-RS's `ResponseBuilder` type. It has an [`entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#entity-java.lang.Object-) method which accepts an `Object`. This method

> Set the response entity in the builder.
>
> Any Java type instance for a response entity, that is supported by the
>   runtime can be passed.

You've passed it a [`StreamingOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) object.

> A type that may be used as a resource method return value or as the
>   entity in a `Response` when the application wishes to stream the output.
>   This is a lightweight alternative to a
>   `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter`.

JAX-RS will have called your resource method, `some_function()`, and will receive a `Response` object in return. When it has that, it will attempt to serialize it. Internally, your JAX-RS implementation likely has a handler that knows how to process `StreamingOutput` entities. All it has to do is invoke its [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-) method.

---

Lambda expression evaluation consists in creating an instance of the corresponding functional interface. In your example, no code has **yet** invoked that functional interface's method. JAX-RS will eventually.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very convincing

Answer (score 1):

**Lambda expressions.** Funda-men-tally, a lambda expression is just a shorter way of writing an implementation of **a method for later execution.**

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1-2080972.html

After the implementation you need to execution:

```
some_function();
```